Solution of following equation
i'm in trouble with the following problem:

Find all values of $k$ give that the following equation has exactly $2$ solutions:
$$ (x^3-3)e^x = k, \quad k \in \mathbb{R}$$

I have that $f'(x) =  e^x(x^3+3x^2-3)$. If I put this derivative equal to $0$ I don't know how to procede.
If I use Wolframalpha i see that the equation $x^3+3x^2-3=0$ has $3$ solutions, but using wolframalpha again with the the $f(x)$ original it says that we have just one minimum.
I don't understand.
Could someone help me please? Thanks

Did you mean “find all values of k”? Because if x is a given number, then the left hand side of the equation would simply be a fixed number, and there would be nothing to solve. It would look something like $123=k$.

@Divide1918 correct. thanks!

Try finding intervals where $g(x)=(x^3-3)e^x$ is increasing/decreasing and it's asymptotes

Look closer at $f$'s plot. It doesn't have "just one minimum".

@AnneBauval thanks. But i can answer to the question?

@Dunham how? If i can't find the zeros of the derivative?

You can find the zeros of a cubic using Cardano's method.

Does this answer your question? An interesting Cubic equation $x^3-3x-1=0$ Of course, first make the substitution $x=y-1$ in your equation $x^3+3x^2-3=0$.
